# mongodb custom sorting like mysql

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to sort a field, but I need to do it like how mysql does and specify the value,

instead of field number sory by -1, 4 3 2 1.

I need to sort it by 2,1,3,4.

is this possible in mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in MongoDB. MongoDB doesn't know which and how many fields exist in a particular document unless the document is retrieved.
Hence MongoDB practically cannot give numbers to specific fields.

> MongoDB is a JSON-style data store. The documents stored in the
>   database can have varying sets of fields, with different types for
>   each field.

In Databases the number and types of the column is fixed by particular table definition and it's easier for a database system to give numbers to the columns.